# How to select distinct records ordered by date column desc - Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, distinct

I have such table:

```
app_id | releaseDate 
111  | 2019-04-21
111  | 2019-05-10
222  | 2019-07-21
222  | 2019-04-22
222  | 2019-05-25
333  | 2019-06-21
333  | 2019-05-21
```

I need to get such result (need to order desc by releaseDate and after select distinct):

```
111 | 2019-05-10
222 | 2019-07-21
333 | 2019-06-21
```

My code:

```
$apps_histories = ApplicationHistory::with('application')->whereBetween('releaseDate', ['2014-10-01', '2019-10-14'])
            ->orderBy('releaseDate', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('app_id')
            ->get();
```

I got:

```
111 | 2019-04-21
222 | 2019-04-22
333 | 2019-05-21
```

I have tried different approaches, but I don't get why it's not working as I expect.
Could you please help?

Comment: If you are using a group by any columns not in the group by should inside aggregate operators like MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG. i.e. MAX(releaseDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior in two ways. The first one is to filter `releaseDate` in the query, using a raw query:

```
$apps_histories = ApplicationHistory::with('application')
        ->whereBetween('releaseDate', ['2014-10-01', '2019-10-14'])
        ->select(\DB::raw('*, max(releaseDate) as releaseDate'))
        ->orderBy('releaseDate', 'DESC')
        ->groupBy('app_id')
        ->get();
```

The other way is using `unique` function in result `Collection`. Just be aware that this option is not optimized for big result tables:

```
$apps_histories = ApplicationHistory::with('application')
        ->whereBetween('releaseDate', ['2014-10-01', '2019-10-14'])
        ->orderBy('releaseDate', 'DESC')
        ->get()
        ->unique('app_id');
```

Comment: both ways are working correct, thx. How much is a big result table (approx.)?

Comment: It depends on the server capacity, but, lets say that your are going to filter 10,000 objects, maybe the second option is not a good idea.